# Critical freeze on login in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, login-screen, freeze

Using an up-to-date Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 system on a msi cx70 sometimes on login screen I can have a freeze. After this I can only reboot machine or call console (ctrl-alt-f1).

What can I do to fix or troubleshoot this issue?

UPD: after steps written by MadMike I got https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnk8vzff8eu120a/log.txt?dl=0 log

What should I do now?

Comment: check /var/log/ and specifically syslog in there for notices.

Comment: Please open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t and issue `sudo -i`, then issue `mkdir /var/log/journal; systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal; systemctl restart systemd-journald`. This will enable to save boot-message over several boot-ups. Should your system freeze, issue `journalctl -b1` to see the previous boot. Select the content with your mouse and copy it into the clipboard with Ctrl+Shift+c. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/785311/edit) your question and add the information.